# ZXing how to scan QR-Code AND 1D barcode?

Tags: android, android-intent, barcode, zxing

I just imported the ZXing library in my app, I know how to set up the `putExtra` function to **scan QR-Code barcode**:

```
INTENT = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
INTENT.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(INTENT, 0);
```

and if I like to scan a **1D barcode**:

```
INTENT = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
INTENT.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
startActivityForResult(INTENT, 0);
```

but how do I make the App able to scan both?? (1D and 2D barcode).

Thanks!
Marco

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you just want to scan both (and not exclusively these two):

Don't add the `SCAN_MODE` extra to the intent. Thats optional to limit the type of barcode to a certain type. Not specifying it will scan all possible types.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know I could do that :) Works perfectly!

Answer (score 7):

Just go through these line of code. It is working for me perfectly as you want.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
              intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android"); 
              //intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
              intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A,QR_CODE");
              startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [IntentIntegrator](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java) it is a class the Zxing project has that I am using with one of my apps. I have provided a link to the file. It encapsulates the scan code and is great for simple scanning function. initiateScan method is where you want to look. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

you should use "SCAN_MODE" instead of "QR_CODE_MODE":

```
INTENT.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
```

should be

```
INTENT.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "SCAN_MODE");
```

Comment: that is as good as not adding `SCAN_MODE` extra. refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21764891/1529129