# ZXing-embedded library scans irrelevant/wrong bar-code values in some cases

Tags: android, xamarin.android, zxing, barcode-scanner, zxing.net

I've implemented native ZXing-embedded library in my Xamarin.Android project and everything's working fine except one issue that when I try to scan the QR or Barcodes from some distance, then it returns some random irrelevant values which are totally different from the original ones. After checking this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764803/zxing-sometimes-picks-up-the-wrong-data-from-barcode) I've tried restricting the scan modes but it made no difference and it is still returning wrong values. Any help would be really appreciable.

Thanks in advance!

## Update 2:

Here's is my code, you can check and let me know if there's something that needs to be corrected in it:

```
public class CustomScannerActivity : Activity, DecoratedBarcodeView.ITorchListener
{
    public const int CUSTOMIZED_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private CaptureManager capture;
    private DecoratedBarcodeView barcodeScannerView;
    private ImageButton switchFlashlightButton;
    private ImageButton cameraButton;
    private ViewfinderView viewfinderView;
    TextView txtViewBottomText;
    private bool torchOn;


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.ActionBar.Hide();
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_custom_scannerview);

        barcodeScannerView = (DecoratedBarcodeView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.zxing_barcode_scanner);
        barcodeScannerView.SetTorchListener(this);

        var greenOverlay = (View)FindViewById(Resource.Id.view1);

        Android.Util.DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        var scanWidth = (int)(displayMetrics.WidthPixels * 0.65);
        barcodeScannerView.BarcodeView.FramingRectSize = new Size(scanWidth, 100);

        greenOverlay.LayoutParameters.Width = scanWidth;
        greenOverlay.LayoutParameters.Height = scanWidth;

        CameraSettings settings = barcodeScannerView.BarcodeView.CameraSettings;

        switchFlashlightButton = (ImageButton)FindViewById(Resource.Id.switch_flashlight);
        cameraButton = (ImageButton)FindViewById(Resource.Id.camera);
        viewfinderView = (ViewfinderView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.zxing_viewfinder_view);
        txtViewBottomText = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.zxing_status_view);

        txtViewBottomText.Text = AppResources.ScanAutomatically;

        if (MainActivity.camPosition)
        {
            settings.RequestedCameraId = Convert.ToInt32(Android.Hardware.CameraFacing.Front);
            switchFlashlightButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            barcodeScannerView.BarcodeView.CameraSettings = settings;
            barcodeScannerView.Resume();
        }
        else
        {
            settings.RequestedCameraId = Convert.ToInt32(Android.Hardware.CameraFacing.Back);
            switchFlashlightButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            barcodeScannerView.BarcodeView.CameraSettings = settings;
            barcodeScannerView.Resume();
        }

        switchFlashlightButton.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (!torchOn && !MainActivity.camPosition)
            {
                barcodeScannerView.SetTorchOn();
            }
            else
            {
                barcodeScannerView.SetTorchOff();
            }
            torchOn = !torchOn;
        };

        cameraButton.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            //CameraSettings settings = barcodeScannerView.BarcodeView.CameraSettings;
            if (barcodeScannerView.BarcodeView.IsPreviewActive)
            {
                barcodeScannerView.Pause();
            }

            //swap the id of the camera to be used
            if (settings.RequestedCameraId == Convert.ToInt32(Android.Hardware.CameraFacing.Front))
            {
                settings.RequestedCameraId = Convert.ToInt32(Android.Hardware.CameraFacing.Back);
                switchFlashlightButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                barcodeScannerView.SetTorchOff();
                MainActivity.camPosition = false;
                barcodeScannerView.BarcodeView.CameraSettings = settings;
                barcodeScannerView.Resume();
            }
            else
            {
                settings.RequestedCameraId = Convert.ToInt32(Android.Hardware.CameraFacing.Front);
                switchFlashlightButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                barcodeScannerView.SetTorchOff();
                MainActivity.camPosition = true;
                barcodeScannerView.BarcodeView.CameraSettings = settings;
                barcodeScannerView.Resume();
            }
        };

        // if the device does not have flashlight in its camera,
        // then remove the switch flashlight button...
        if (!hasFlash())
        {
            switchFlashlightButton.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }

        capture = new CaptureManager(this, barcodeScannerView);
        capture.InitializeFromIntent(Intent, savedInstanceState);
        capture.Decode();

    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        if (capture != null)
        {
            capture.OnResume();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        if (capture != null)
        {
            capture.OnPause();
        }

    }

    protected override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
        if (capture != null)
        {
            capture.OnDestroy();
        }

    }

    protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (capture != null)
        {
            capture.OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

    }

    //public override bool OnKeyDown([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
    //{
    //    return barcodeScannerView.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e) || base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
    //}

    private bool hasFlash()
    {
        return this.ApplicationContext.PackageManager.HasSystemFeature(Android.Content.PM.PackageManager.FeatureCameraFlash);//"android.hardware.camera.flash"
    }

    public void OnTorchOff()
    {

    }

    public void OnTorchOn()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You can post some code.It is possible that the frame is aligned with the QR code, and the QR code is stretched and deformed, and the correct result cannot be scanned!

Comment: Thanks @JuniorJiang-MSFT for your response. I've updated my code, please take a look.

Comment: @NidhiSood can you elaborate more how you ignore to scan wrong values ?